# Detect if touch device with ie11 using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to use javascript to detect if my visitor is on a touch device or not.

I have the following...

```
function is_touch_device() {
    return 'ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; 
}
```

The above works fine apart from ie11 is returning true, that it is a touch device when in reality it isnt. Has anybody experienced this before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code snippet might help:

```
function is_touch_device() {
 return (('ontouchstart' in window)
      || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0)
      || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
 //navigator.msMaxTouchPoints for microsoft IE backwards compatibility
}
```

Comment: Fix above is slightly incorrect. navigator.MaxTouchPoints shold be navigator.maxTouchPoints with lower case "m"